# graphing the solution of $y'=x^2-3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a Ordinary Differential Equation(ODE)

[image]

and I got the solution as

[image]
​

Now I want to draw graph? How can I do that?

I think:

```
if y=0 x got some value (ignoring K)
y = 1 x got another some value
y = 2 x got another some value  and so on..
```

Then what become K.

Is this the correct method?
 Please anyone help me to find the solution. Is there any mistake in my approach?
​

Comment: Your solution as it stands gives a *family* of solutions to the ODE. You would need extra information to sketch a *particular* solution to the ODE, namely something like 'when $x=0$, $y=2$'etc...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me remark that your ODE means "Find all primitives of the function $x \mapsto x^2 -3$. As you noticed, there are infinitely many primitives, and hence infinitely many solutions to your ODE. These solutions are parametrized by the real parameter $K$.

As a consequence, you cannot draw a graph of *the* solution: you should draw infinitely many graphs. However, it is immediate to see that if you draw the graph of $y=\frac{x^3}{3}-3x$, all other graphs are otained by translating this particular graph upwards or downwards. I guess you can draw the graph of a polynomial.

In general there are many ways to single out a particular solution from the family of all solutions. The most elementary is to prescribe an initial condition like $y(x_0)=y_0$. In your case this would be equivalent to
$$
y_0=\frac{x_0^3}{3}-3x_0+K,
$$
or
$$
K=y_0-\frac{x_0^3}{3}+3x_0.
$$